# Post Titles/Post Content Displaying Twice

Tags: spam

We’ve recently had a membership registration spamming, which I believe has caused several issues:

1. Some post titles are displaying twice on our home page (http://www.ondemandweekly.com) and in the Most Popular Post listings
2. Content is duplicated within posts themselves
3. Post author has been reassigned to a bogus spam author

I’ve turned off membership registration and changed my member trigger word, as well as optimized my tables, and it seems to have resolved the member registration spam issue; however, I’m not sure how to repair the double post display issue.

Some posts actually duplicated themselves, and I’ve deleted any duplicates from the admin panel; however, the double title display and duplicate content within posts remain.

We are using EE1.7.1.

Any help is appreciated. I’ve never used SQL, by the way, so please reply at a basic level.

Thank you!

```
{embed="global/head" loc="home"} 

<div id="articles" class="grid_12"> 

    {exp:weblog:entries weblog="blog" limit="1" orderby="date" paginate="bottom" status="featured" } 

        <h2 id="top-headline"><a href="{title_permalink="blog/article"}">{title}</a><span>more &hellip;</span></h2> 

    {/exp:weblog:entries} 

    <div class="row clearfix"> 

    <div class="grid_4 alpha"> 

        {embed="blog/stories-for-home-page" category_1="38"} 

    </div>

    <div class="grid_4"> 
        {embed="blog/stories-for-home-page" category_1="40"} 
    </div> 

    <div class="grid_4 omega"> 
        {embed="blog/stories-for-home-page" category_1="43"} 
    </div> 
</div> 

<div class="row clearfix"> 

    <div class="grid_4 alpha"> 

        {embed="blog/stories-for-home-page" category_1="36"} 

    </div> 

    <div class="grid_4"> 

        {embed="blog/stories-for-home-page" category_1="42"} 

    </div> 

    <div class="grid_4 omega"> 

        {embed="blog/stories-for-home-page" category_1="41"} 

    </div> 

</div> 

{embed="ads/featured_video" loc="home"} 

{embed="blog/recent-posts" loc="home"} </div>

<div class="grid_4"> 

    <div id="ad"> 

        {embed="ads/160x1600" loc="home"} 

        {embed="blog/twitter-widget" loc="home"} 

    </div> 
</div> 

{embed="global/footer"}
```

Comment: Can you post your template code here. Has someone tried to "fix" the spam registrations by restoring the database or some other database fiddling?

Comment: I've gone through and deleted the spam registrations from the admin panel. Below is our code for the home page where the double post is showing at the top of the page, and at the bottom in the recent entries (most popular posts) section.

Comment: Code is too long so I need to separate in different comments. Part 1:'{embed="global/head" loc="home"}
<div id="articles" class="grid_12">
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="blog" limit="1" orderby="date" paginate="bottom" status="featured" }
<h2 id="top-headline"><a href="{title_permalink="blog/article"}">{title}</a><span>more &hellip;</span></h2>

{/exp:weblog:entries} 

<div class="row clearfix">
<div class="grid_4 alpha">
{embed="blog/stories-for-home-page" category_1="38"}
</div>

Comment: Part 2: '

<div class="grid_4">
{embed="blog/stories-for-home-page" category_1="40"}
</div>

<div class="grid_4 omega">
{embed="blog/stories-for-home-page" category_1="43"}
</div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix">
<div class="grid_4 alpha">
{embed="blog/stories-for-home-page" category_1="36"}
</div>

<div class="grid_4">
{embed="blog/stories-for-home-page" category_1="42"}
</div>


<div class="grid_4 omega">
{embed="blog/stories-for-home-page" category_1="41"}
</div>
</div>
{embed="ads/featured_video" loc="home"}

{embed="blog/recent-posts" loc="home"}

</div>'

Comment: Part 3: 
'
<div class="grid_4">
<div id="ad">
{embed="ads/160x1600" loc="home"}
{embed="blog/twitter-widget" loc="home"}
</div>
</div>
{embed="global/footer"}'

Comment: I've added the code to the question for clarity. What you have posted is actually code that pulls in other template code so it's difficult to diagnose the issue. Also, I can't see the issue on your site. Can you provide a link to a page where this is happening and the template code that is generating it?